# Problem with asigning non-irrational values to irrational arrays using broadcast .=

Tags: julia

Take as example following (irrational) array

```
a = fill(pi, 10)
```

When trying to assign a different value to one element, for example

```
a[1] .= 0.0
```

Following error occurs:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching copyto!(::Irrational{:π}, ::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0},Tuple{},typeof(identity),Tuple{Int64}})
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that the element type of `a` when you construct it like that is the special number typ `Irrational{:π}` as seen from the output:

```
julia> a = fill(pi, 2)
2-element Array{Irrational{:π},1}:
 π
 π
```

When you try to put another numeric type in this container (e.g. a `Float64` with value `0.0` in your example) it is like trying to fit squares in circular holes -- they don't fit.

The solution is to construct the array with the desired element type to start with. For "regular" computations you probably want `Float64`, so you can convert `pi` to a float first:

```
julia> a = fill(float(pi), 2)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 3.141592653589793
 3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 1):

The two other answers suggest you to convert your `pi` to `Float64`. In Julia you do not have to do that.

```
v = fill!(Vector{Union{Float64,Irrational}}(undef,10), pi)
```

Now your vector `v` can store both Float64 and Irrational numbers. Note that the performance of such code will be worse than having just a `Vector{Float64}` but on the other hand you are not forced to loose precision (which might be desirable or not).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we use broadcast to vectorialize operation : if you want to change all the values of the array a, you write

```
a .= 0.0
```

And if you want to change only the first value, you write

```
a[1] = 0.0
```

wich gives now a different error

**ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Irrational{:π}(::Float64)**

The problem comes frome the type. As you can see here, https://julialang.org/blog/2017/03/piday/ irrational is some kind of weird type. Shortly, it's only used to stock some classical values ( pi, e, ...) wich can be converted to any floating type without any intermediate routine.

It's a bit strange to set an array of irrational, I think you would prefer to use Float64. If I take your original declation, write

```
a = fill( Float64(pi), 10 )
```

an then you can use

```
a[1] = 0.0
```

or

```
a .= 0.0
```